# Get Post meta via XML-RPC using wp.getPost

Tags: xml-rpc

I am trying to get the value of two post meta fields using wp.getPost.

I can get custom fields and the normal post fields but I can't seem to get the meta values associated with the post.

I have some custom postMeta that I have put in place called "_swmc_no_comment" and I want to be able to get the value of that. The codex isn't 100% clear on this, or at least my reading of it is poor and all experiments I try seem to fail

Can anyone give me any pointers on getting the post meta of a post via xml-rpc?

Cheers
Dan

Answer (score 1):

the filter `xmlrpc_default_post_fields` can modify the defult fields sent in rpc, but the defults `array( 'post', 'terms', 'custom_fields' )` alredy include custom_fields

you also have the filter `xmlrpc_prepare_post`, where you can add extra stuff to the rpc:s post

Comment: Hmm custom_fields only returns custom fields though. What I want is meta, that I have added via a server side plugin.

add_post_meta($post->ID, '_swmc_no_comment',  'redrafted', true) or

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta says "Adds a custom field (also called meta-data) to a specified post", so for me it looks like meta and custom_fields are the same, whats the difference between them in your point of view?

Comment: The difference simply that XML-RPC comes up as having no custom_fields in the response, i.e. [custom_fields] => Array
        (
        )

however when I pull the meta on wordpress through 
get_post_meta($post_id, '_swmc_no_comment', true);

I get the value "on" or off depending on the post

Comment: Until I find a way I have worked around it in my scripts on the RPC client side and ping backs send a flag in the URL so this will work until I find a solution to get meta